# Difference between 2 date objects in days

Tags: java, android, date, android-date

I am doing an android project and I have 2 date objects

1. Fri Apr 17 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015
2. Thu Apr 16 21:12:27 GMT+05:30 2015

Here difference b/w these 2 dates is not 24 hrs, but as the day changes from Thu to Fri I need the difference as 1.

Please help..

Comment: How do you want to handle DST changes? If you don't care about those, and you're really just interested in view 1 day == 24 hours, then you can just call `getTime()` on each `Date`, subtract one value from the other, and divide by the number of milliseconds in a day.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he wants the answer to be 1 day, if the difference was less than 24 hours but the start date was the day before.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Exactly. you got my requirement. Please help if you have answer or share related links.

Comment: @user2085965: I've already given you a suggestion *and* closed the question as the duplicate of another...

Comment: @JonSkeet: let me confirm, Joda Time is your recommended solution.?

Comment: @user2085965: Yes, I'd use Joda Time. You need to consider what time zone you want. I'd convert the `Instant` to a `DateTime`, then take the `LocalDate` from that, then use `Period` to find the number of days.